# Java Decimal to Time Conversion

Tags: java

How can I convert a decimal to Time in java.

Example:

```
Double takttime = 1.08;  //Which is 1 Minutes 4 Seconds.
```

Results separated by Hours, minutes, seconds.

Comment: I dont think any class exist in java which do this.If you want only in java then add your logic or may b any external library can to do this

Comment: How does 1.08 translate to 1 minute, 48 seconds?

Comment: Maybe 1 hour and .08 is 1 min 48 seconds?

Comment: @femtoRgon 1.08 minutes is 1 minutes and 48 seconds.  (60 * 0.8)

Comment: @femtoRgon yes there is an error in is question. like MrTi said, probaly he meant 1 hour 4 minutes and 8 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
double takttime = 1.08;

int t = (int) ( 100 * takttime * 60 );

int hour = t/3600;
t %= 3600;
int min = t/60;
t %= 60;
int sec = t;
```

or ... maybe:

```
double takttime = 1.08;

int t = (int) ( 100 * takttime);

int min = t/100;
int sec = 60 * (t%100)
```

depending on what you need exactly.

Comment: Thanks, I has having a heck of a time putting it all together. Your first example worked nicely just had to remove the hours int.

Answer (score 4):

### java.time, the modern Java date and time API

Since Java 9:

```
    double takttime = 1.08;  //Which is 1 Minutes 4 Seconds.
    
    double nanos = takttime * Duration.ofMinutes(1).toNanos();
    Duration dur = Duration.ofNanos(Math.round(nanos));
    
    long hours = dur.toHours();
    int minutes = dur.toMinutesPart();
    int seconds = dur.toSecondsPart();
    
    System.out.format("Hours: %d; minutes: %d; seconds: %d%n", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Output is:

> Hours: 0; minutes: 1; seconds: 4

The `toXxx`methods of `Duration` convert the entire duration to that unit whereas `toXxxPart` exclude greater units from the conversion. For example with our `Duration` `toSeconds()` would yield 64 seconds for 1 minute 4 seconds. `toSecondsPart()`, as we have seen, yields just 4 seconds.

**Tutorial link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Why are you using toNanos() rather than toSeconds()?

Comment: In this case it doesn’t matter, @fidekild. `Duration` has nanosecond precision, so for other durations using `toSeconds()` might throw away precision. It’s just a habit of taking the finest precision available.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment! I was wondering if I was missing something. Your answer was still useful 7 years later :)

Comment: @fidekild To add a little more precision: My code produces a `Duration` of 1 minute 4.8 seconds. So inside the code I have finer than second precision. I prefer to have that and do any truncation only in the output.

Comment: Worked for my code changin "ofMinutes(1)" to "ofHours(1)", as I needed the hours values

Answer (score 2):

```
    long hours = Math.round(Math.floor(hoursInDecimal));
    long minutes = Math.round(Math.floor((hoursInDecimal - hours) * 60));
    long seconds = Math.round(((((hoursInDecimal - hours) * 60) - minutes) * 60));
    
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose `takeTime` is the time in minutes. then:

```
double taktTime = 1.8;
long timeInMilliSeconds = (long) Math.floor(taktTime * 60 * 1000);
Date date = new Date(timeInMilliSeconds);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Comment: Very nice, Though I don't need to format the time, I will keep this snippet in my back pocket

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, Decimal to Time Format conversion:

```
val decimalValue = 0.4444555
val date = Date((decimalValue * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L).roundToLong())
val formatTime = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
formatTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
println(formatTime.format(date))
```

Hope this useful, who want to implement in **KOTLIN**.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Also you’re misusing the (equally outdated) `Date` class. A `Date` is a point in time, it’s not a duration.