# Get total hours and minutes from 10 values

Tags: java

I have list of decimal values like...

```
1.30
1.00
1.50
2.50
2.10
```

I want to calculate total hours  and minutes from this list.

can you please help me how to do it ?

I want this in java.

Comment: first step is to write some code

Comment: Tell us what you have tried until now so we can help

Comment: Convert all the values to minutes and then calculate total hours and minutes.                 Total hours=Total minutes/60 and.               minutes= total minutes % 60

Comment: Please try to do yourself first. if you fails then share if what you did and what problem you faced. Then people will be happy to help you.

Comment: What do those decimal values represent? Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22358642/642706

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this can help you :

```
public class TimeCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long sumOfMilliSeconds = 0;
        double array[] = new double[] {
                1.30, 1.00, 1.50, 2.50, 2.10

        };
        for (double d : array) {
            sumOfMilliSeconds = sumOfMilliSeconds + convertToMilliSecounds(d);
        }
        convertDateformat(sumOfMilliSeconds);
    }

    public static void convertDateformat(long milliSeconds) {

        Date date = new Date(milliSeconds);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    }

    public static long convertToMilliSecounds(double taktTime) {
        long timeInMilliSeconds = (long) (taktTime * 60 * 1000);
        return timeInMilliSeconds;
    }

}
```

Comment: The troublesome `Date` class is now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes, specifically `Instant`. Suggesting these awful legacy classes in 2018 is a disservice. Also, using `double` is ill-advised as that type is inaccurate.